# What is the difference between sklearn.optimize and skopt?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization

I have been developing some Python code (3.6.3) which uses the 'optimize' function from the sklearn.optimize package to optimize a function and it has been behaving badly.  The function is accessed by

```
from sklearn.optimize import minimize
```

To help with the debugging, it occurred to me that I could recreate the code in a Docker container on another machine, but every time I do a Google search on

> python how to install sklearn.optimize

I end up with instructions for installing scikit-optimize.  The names are similar, but they are not the same.  The closest that I can come to getting the same function is

```
from skopt import gp_minimize
```

Did something happen to sklearn.optimize?  Has it been superseded by scikit-optimize?  Is scikit-optimize just the latest version of the same package?  Why is there no mention of any relationship between the two?

I may be able to do what I want to do using skopt.gp_minimize, but I would feel a lot better about it if I understood what has happened and what, if any, the relationship is.

Comment: Scikit-optimize is a super useful, well maintaned package, and you can find docs and repo here: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/index.html and https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/tree/de32b5fd2205a1e58526f3cacd0422a26d315d0f. I am not sure what you mean by sklearn.optimize. Could you share a link to said package?